# What is the best way for user and staff authentication in a single application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

My website needs to authenticate both website's users and website's staff, which are like admins, seperately.

I want my website's users who are loggedIn and already are authenticated with claims, can't access to my Admin's CRM.

What is the best way for the situation ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you want separate endpoints for admin and user authentication.

let's say `api/admin/login` is for the admin. You can check if the user is in the admin role BEFORE authenticating the user i.e. before checking if they've supplied the correct signin credentials.

```
public async Task AdminLogin(string email) 
{
    var user = _userManager.GetUserByEmail(email);
    if (!_userManager.IsUserInRole(user, "admin"))
    {
          return StatusCode("403");
    } 
   ... If successful, authenticate user credentials here
}
```

You do the same for user login endpoint.